# How to change label color in Morris.js charts?

Tags: javascript, html, graph, morris.js

I'm using morris.js charts which are fantastically easy to setup but I can't workout how to change the color for labels when rendering a Donut graph. By default it prints them in black but I want the graph on top of a dark background.

Does anyone know how to change the label color?

Answer (score 4):

```
<div id="bar-chart" class="morris-chart" style="height: 180px"></div>

.morris-chart text {
  fill: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the label color, simply add `labelColor` property to Morris.Donut config object like below

```
Morris.Donut({
  labelColor: '#FFF'
});
```